# Add Sequential Letter column to table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In C I can switch between int and char to build a list of sequential integers and then convert them to ASCII characters that will be sequential according to the alphabet.

Is there a way to do this in postgres to get a column with row values "A","B","C" etc...?

the only way I can think of would be to start with a `SERIAL` column of ints and then write a `CASE` to set each row individually. The Tables big enough that it would be much preferred to do this automatically somehow.

Comment: What happens after `Z`?

Comment: was thinking `AA` excel style.

Comment: Like this: [Calculate MS Excel column name from its number in PostgreSQL](https://gist.github.com/mlt/2e26dda28dae2dac9a345e35834c5526)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: [Calculate MS Excel column name from its number in PostgreSQL](https://gist.github.com/mlt/2e26dda28dae2dac9a345e35834c5526)

```
CREATE FUNCTION excel_column(col integer)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
WITH RECURSIVE t(n, out) AS (
    SELECT col/26-(col%26=0)::int, chr((col-1)%26 + 65)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n/26-(n%26=0)::int, chr((n-1)%26 + 65) || out FROM t
    where n>0
)
SELECT out FROM t where n=0;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE LEAKPROOF STRICT;
```

Usage:

```
select excel_column(x) from generate_series(1,800) x;
```

Result:

```
A
B
..
AA
AB
..
ZZ
AAA
..
ADT
```

Comment: nice, that's exactly what I'm looking to avoid having to port from C https://github.com/HughKelley/CS50/blob/master/pset2/vigenere/vigenere.c

Comment: some users will want to remove `LEAKPROOF` depending on their user role, i.e. if they don't have admin privileges.